# Date format problems

Tags: windows, powershell

I´m trying to get the month with 05 format.

I´m executing:

```
PS C:\Users\olopez> (Get-date).adddays(-1).month
5
PS C:\Users\olopez>
```

How can I change the 5 format to 05?

I have tried with something like this:

```
PS C:\Users\olopez> $a= get-date -format d ((get-date).adddays(-1))
PS C:\Users\olopez>  $a=Get-date -format dd-MM-yyyy
PS C:\Users\olopez> [datetime]::parseexact($a,"dd-MM-yyyy",$null)

Thursday, May 22, 2014 12:00:00 AM


PS C:\Users\olopez> [datetime]::parseexact($a,"dd-MM-yyyy",$null).month
5
PS C:\Users\olopez>
```

Obiously it returns 5 again :).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
(Get-date).adddays(-1).ToString("MM")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
get-date -format MM
```

Returns 05